# Why emails are not sending from my website?

Tags: yii2, hosting, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I am facing issue while sending email using `Yii2 swiftmailer`. I can't forward emails from my website.

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'transport' => [
 'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
                'username' => 'hr@hrconnectnorth.com',
                'password' => 'mypassword',
                'port' => '465',
                'encryption' => 'ssl',
            ],
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
```

What should I do for it?

I can't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you have [useFileTransport](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-mail-basemailer#$useFileTransport-detail) set to true. If you set it to True the email messages will be saved as files under $fileTransportPath instead of sending them to the actual recipients.

Answer (score 0):

any error message?
`'enableSwiftMailerLogging' => true,`
You can write and view the error log using the.

If it is giving error with ssl, you can get rid of ssl error by below code

```php
'transport' => [
    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
    'host' => 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
    'username' => 'hr@hrconnectnorth.com',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'port' => '465',
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'streamOptions' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'streamOptions' => ['ssl' => ['verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false]],
    'streamOptions' => ['ssl' => ['allow_self_signed' => true]],
    'streamOptions' => ['ssl' => ['verify_depth' => false]],
],
'enableSwiftMailerLogging' => true,
```

> Setting verify_peer to false can potentially expose your application to security risks, as it disables the verification of the peer's SSL/TLS certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the 'useFileTransport' option set as false. You set it as true This means emails will not be sent via the SMTP server but saved in the file system under the runtime/mail directory. This could be the reason why your email is not being sent.